# Issues making a histogram with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, histogram

I want to plot a simple histogram of height, weight and age, being age in the x-axis using ggplot

First I build the different measures and make the dataframe:

```
age <- seq(from=10, to=21)
age

height <- c(147,152,157,160,163,172,177,180,183,184,185,185)
height

weight <- c(47,54,61,63,65,66,69,72,79,81,82,83)
weight

df <- data.frame(age,height,weight, stringsAsFactors = F)
df$age <- as.numeric(df$age)


df$class[df$age <14] = "child"
df$class[df$age <=17 & df$age>=14] = "teen"
df$class[df$age >17] = "adult"
df
```

And then I make a simple histogram:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=age, y=height))+geom_histogram(fill="white",color="black",stat="identity",bins=12)
```

The problem is that the histogram keeps showing up like a bar chart, with the variable age looking like a discreet variable rather than a continuous one and without giving the assigned year to each bar:

[image: graph]

And also I get this error message:

> Warning message:
>   "Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad"

I have tried with `scale_x_continuous`, `scale_y_continuous`, without them, with only `scale_x_continuous`, I checked if the variable age was numerical and still the same problems. Maybe I'm missing a very simple thing, I'm not sure, but I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a histogram of `age` by `height` you must pass `weight = height` as an `geom_histogram` aesthetic, not as a `y` coordinate.
I also redid the data set in a simpler way, using `cut` to define the (unneeded) `class` vector.

```
age <- 10:21
height <- c(147,152,157,160,163,172,177,180,183,184,185,185)
weight <- c(47,54,61,63,65,66,69,72,79,81,82,83)
class <- cut(age, 
             breaks = c(0, 14, 17, Inf), 
             labels = c("child", "teen", "adult"))
df <- data.frame(age, height, weight, class, stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(df, aes(age)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(weight = height),
                 fill = "white", 
                 color = "black", 
                 bins = 12)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for your answer